# Json deserialize to specific Java class subtype without sending @class or @type from frontend

Tags: json, spring, deserialization, typeinfo

I'm a junior and am working on a chat app, Angular for frontend and Spring boot for Backend, and an external library called `ChatServer`. In my BFF i'm using the models from the `ChatServer`. One of those models is called `ChatMessage`:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public class ChatMessage extends ChatPackage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    private String body;
    private Map<String, Serializable> values;

    public ChatMessage(ChatRoom room, ChatUser from, Date timetamp, String body) {
        this(room,from,timetamp, body, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public ChatMessage(ChatRoom room, ChatUser from, Date timestamp, String body,
            Map<String, Serializable> values) {
        super(room, from, timestamp);
        this.body = body;
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Due to the constructor structure in this library class, from my Angular frontend I'm sending a `ChatMessageDTO`:

```
export interface ChatMessageDTO {
  room: ChatRoom;
  from: ChatUser;
  timestamp: Date;
  message: ChatMessage;
}
```

and in my BFF I have a similar DTO for incoming requests:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ChatMessageDTO {
  private ChatRoom room;
  private ChatUser from;
  private Date timestamp;
  private ChatMessage message;

}
```

But i get this error in my BFF:

```
10:49:14.705 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod - Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> ChatController.sendMessage(chat.model.ChatMessageDTO): JSON parse error: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class chat.data.ChatMessage]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'message')
```

I've read [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization), as well as many other sources - and my understanding is that the only way for this to work is to send @class from the frontend. I've tried it and it works, but it looks like an ugly fix, since my model will look like:

```
export interface ChatMessageDTO {
  room: ChatRoom;
  from: ChatUser;
  timestamp: Date;
  message: ChatMessage;
 '@class': 'classpath.etc.etc'
}
```

I have not yet found a better and cleaner way for this to work. Is there really no better way? Do i need to hardcode this parameter in my frontend?

Thank you